# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) in Django

Tags: python, django

I am pulling data with where conditions and trying to print the object but it's throwing error `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) in Django` help me with this error as I am learning Django

This is my function

```
def example_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    abc = request.data.get('abc')
    xyz = request.data.get('xyz')
    for obj in User.objects.raw('select * from public."Example_App_user" where abc = %s and xyz = %s',[abc,xyz]):
        print(obj)
```

This is my Model

```
class User(models.Model):
abc = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
xyz = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.abc
```

Comment: Did you print `abc` and `xyz` to make sure you're actually getting a value?

Comment: Can you show your models file?

Comment: Share your `User` model.

Comment: @ThatcherThornberry question is updated with model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem question is updated with model.

Comment: `self.abc` can be `None`, so in that case `__str__` will return `None`, not a string.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I am getting values.

Answer (score 1):

__str__ in model should return string:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.abc)
```

or in case when `abc is None` to avoid `"None"` and get empty string `""`:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.abc or ""
```